# How to access configured values when using Action delegate

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I'm trying to learn about *Action* delegates, but I'm missing something - how to access the configured values?

**MyOptions.cs**:

```
public class CustomOptions
{
    public int AppId { get; set; }
}
```

**Service to register**:

```
public static IApplicationBuilder UseMyService(this IApplicationBuilder builder, Action<CustomOptions> options)
```

When I register the service I do: app.UseMyService(o => o.AppId = 1);

But how can I access AppId from inside the service? Or am I missing something? Should I use Func instead?

Comment: What does your `UseMyService` method look like? I'd expect your service constructor to accept a `CustomOptions` that's then injected like any other dependency, but I admit I haven't written any custom middleware myself.

Comment: `var optionsInstance = new MyOptions(); options.?Invoke(optionsInstance)`. After that, `optionsInstance` is populated with the value passed in UseMyService

Answer (score 4):

A delegate is nothing else than an reference to a method. You can either pass anonymous methods to it (as delegate or lambdas) or a named method whose parameter match the delegate signature.

```
public static IApplicationBuilder UseMyService(this IApplicationBuilder builder, Action<CustomOptions> options)
{
    var defaultOptions = new CustomOptions();
    // you can initialize defaultOptions here with default vaues

    // then invoke the delegate to override specific values
    options?.Invoke(defaultOptions);
}
```

This way you don't have to fill all parameters when you set it up via

```
app.UseMyService(options => {
    options.AppId = 2;
});
```